# Why is this View Model being populated when I pass "" into RenderAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, renderaction, actionmethod

I'm trying to implement a Widget control that exists on every page in the system, which will allow the user to have basic Search & Directory functionality available on each page. This is a tab control defined below, where in the `<ul>` the currently selected tab is determined by the the value in `Model.CurrentTab` and the corresponding content that I want to display (basically, make visible) is also determined by that value.

```
<div class="WidgetControl">

    <ul class="WidgetTab tabs">
        <li <%= (Model.CurrentTab == "Search") ? "class='active'" : "" %>>
            <span href='<%= Url.Action("SearchBox", "Search") %>'>Search</span>
        </li>

        <li <%= (Model.CurrentTab == "Directory") ? "class='active'" : "" %>>
            <span href='<%= Url.Action("DirectoryList", "Group") %>'>Directory</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="Search" class="tab_container">
        <% Html.RenderAction("SearchBox", "Search"
                    , (Model.CurrentTab == "Search") ? Model.Search : ""); %>
    </div>

    <div id="Directory" class="tab_container">
        <% Html.RenderAction("DirectoryList", "Group"
                    , (Model.CurrentTab == "Directory") ? Model.Search : ""); %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I want to load both `Search` and `Directory` is so the page doesn't have to request the content depending on which tab is clicked. I want it all to be available immediately.

The problem I'm having is that if `CurrentTab` contains the value "Directory" this means (I assumed) that `Html.RenderAction("SearchBox"...` should pass in an empty string. But when it gets to the action method, the View Model passed into `SearchBox` contains a value and not `""`

I don't understand why this is happening. Even when I pass an empty string into `SearchBox`, the View Model still contains a value. Can somebody please explain what's going on? Should I be doing this differently?

**update:**

```
    public PartialViewResult DirectoryList(DirectoryViewModel vm)
    {
        return PartialView(vm.Search); // this is expecting a string
    }

    public PartialViewResult SearchBox(SearchViewModel vm)
    {
        return PartialView(vm); // the among other things, the Search string is used
    }
```

Both `DirectoryViewModel` and `SearchViewModel` contain a property called `Search`

Comment: can you show us the method definitions for both DirectoryList & SearchBox? I'm having a hard time working out whats going on.

Comment: Sharing what value the model has incorrectly would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ModelBinder will new() up any object in a ActionMethod's parameters. I don't think this behavior can be turned off without implementing your own modelbidner.  You need to create an overload that has no parameters and route it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be doing something like this

```
 <% Html.RenderAction("SearchBox", "Search", 
                    new { vm = ((Model.CurrentTab == "Search") ? Model.Search : "") }); %>
```

Since the third parameter of the `Html.RenderAction` is `object routeValues` which is a dictionary with a parameter of the Action you are calling as a `Key`.  If you don't specify the parameter that you are passing in your `routeValues` parameter of your `Html.RenderAction` it will always pass an `object` value to the `vm` parameter of your Action.